# How to compare salary scales with the current employees' salaries by combining column chart as salary scale and scatter plot chart as employees salary

Tags: excel, charts, analysis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5jX4.png)As mentioned above on the subject I want to present the current employees' salaries and the company salary scales by combining two charts in one chart (column chart and scatter plot) as the attached picture.

column chart = company salary scale

scatter plot = the current employees' salaries.

So, I can see who is below and above the ranges. Please I need a way to do this in excel.

I tries doing it in excel but I couldn't a find a proper way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.